# How does pathfinding in RTS games work?

Tags: ai, path-finding, game-mechanics, search

[crossposted from stackoverflow]

In a game such as Warcraft 3 or Age of Empires, the ways that an AI opponent can move about the map seem almost limitless. The maps are huge and the position of other players is constantly changing.

How does the AI path-finding in games like these work? Standard graph-search methods (such as DFS, BFS or A*) seem impossible in such a setup.

Comment: Why would A* not work in this graph?

Answer (score 31):

In most cases, using [A*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) over a [navigation mesh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navigation_mesh) (commonly referred to as a "navmesh") is the pathfinding solution commercial RTSs use. There is a detailed explanation of how navmeshes work, why they are a better solution than waypoint systems, and links to implementation resources, [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150905073624/http://www.ai-blog.net/archives/000152.html).

If you're planning on developing special game modes (point/node capture) or units that patrol, take cover, etc., you will probably want to implement a waypoint layer atop your navmesh, to control AI behavior (**not pathfinding**).

Answer (score 19):

Check out the [Flowfield](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bovlsENv1g4) algorithm used in Supreme Commander 2. It does a much better job than most RTS pathfinding systems do (skip ahead to 0:50 for a few examples.)

Comment: that is a really cool demo but tells me nothing about the implementation itself

Comment: They mentioned in one sentence - it's based on UW's crowd flow research, which you can find at http://grail.cs.washington.edu/projects/crowd-flows/.

Comment: The flowfield algorithm seems pretty interesting, and definitely seems to do a much better job of pathing than most algorithms, but I wish there was public documentation on how the system itself worked, not just how the system it's based on works. Naturally, there are a lot of questions developers should ask before implementing a core system like this, but, in this case, it seems the only way to answer those questions is to implement the system first. :(

Comment: Although a very impressive video, it seems like overkill for RTS games that deal with fewer units.

Comment: @Kragen: You really only need two units before plain A* (especially waypointed) causes them to bump into each other over and over, and you need some kind of system to work around it.

Comment: Based on the video, Starcraft 2's pathfinding looks like this. Does SC2 use flowfield?

Comment: Supreme Commander 2's pathfinding isn't perfect though, and at least one person argues it's not real pathfinding: http://www.rageeffect.com/post/982193331/supcom-2-flowfield-pathfinding

Comment: The video has been removed by the uploader.

Answer (score 7):

Many older games do use A*.  The original Starcraft used A*; which led to some problems in dealing with collision.  Starcraft 2's handles collision very well, using a swaming/flocking behavior to maintain fluid control of large groups.  [This](http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=563819) gamedev article discusses how this might be being achieve.

Answer (score 2):

I agree upon the other answers her already, but also, try to think of WoW/Warcraft3 as actual 2D worlds. They arent that different from tilebased, its just the tiles.

You could also think of how does a GPS find the best path? there a loads of algortimns for pathfinding through linked maps.

I think some of the first "Quake bots" scripts also might help you, as they were developed to work in "unknown areas" because we could design our own levels from scratch.

All in all, my personal way to deal with such a map, would be to think of it as the A* pathfinder. But first I would pre-calc every "tile point" and index all these with "nearest neighbour" etc. Then when an object needed to go from A to B then just lookup in B, see to what its connected and keep repeating until you reach the goal.

Depending on the type of game and landscape/scenario, different pre-scan tactics might be usefull too. Some games have very little obstracles and these can be "streight line" movement + some "how do I get around" for objects.

Hope this makes a little sense and perhaps gave you some thoughts to work with.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with other answers that the A* algorithm (or variants) is used often, but in some old RTS games (eg: Command & Conquer / Warcraft 1) a simpler and faster approach is used.

It works this way :
project an imaginary line-of-sight from the unit position to its destination.
Most of the time, there is no obstacle between unit and target, and it can stop there since it already found the closest path.

If obstacles are found (eg: trees), the algorithm try to get around it by moving around the edges. To do this, the unit is rotated a certain number of degrees (eg: 45) until it can move again. It check two paths : left and right path (depending unit orientation when obstacle is encountered) and it take the shortest one. While moving around the edges, it try to move back towards the imaginary line-of-sight (which might not be possible because there are still obstacles).

[image]

Once unit is back to the imaginary line-of-sight, it resume path finding from there. More obstacles might be encountered and so on. It stops once target is reached.

It can result in a suboptimal path but on the other hand, it's really cheap to compute. In some extreme cases, unit might get lost (no path was found while there is at least one).

[image]

(from Warcraft 1 : peasant has to backtrack, resulting in suboptimal path)

Sources :

- Command & Conquer [https://github.com/electronicarts/CnC_Remastered_Collection](https://github.com/electronicarts/CnC_Remastered_Collection/blob/master/REDALERT/FINDPATH.CPP#L432)
- Warcraft 1 : personal research

Answer (score 1):

I'm totally not experienced, but I think that a good solution is based on heuristics, not on a complete checking of the known map. Heuristics I can think of are locally based and experience based. Local controls can be based on local terrain check and obstacles, keeping moving toward the required direction. I think that most maps don't require complex maze-like movements, but are pretty connected.
Another heuristic is to use previous known paths (explored by other units or explicitly by the user) to move units to known or near-known positions.
But I'm talking about moving on big maps, not really in closed spaces like ZorbaTHut said. In crowded cases the algorithm may be more complex, requiring sorts of "prediction", coordination among units of the same team or just semaphore-like waiting strategies. Also, note that continuous or discrete terrain and unit size calculation are really important when working on this case.

I think heuristic algorithms are good because they usually provide a good solution on big spaces with a reasonable computation time (which does matter, when you're moving many units).

Sorry if this a generic answer: I worked with crowds, but the space was pretty peculiar and I can't explain exactly how the algorithm worked (was agent based, anyway, not globally defined). I hope you can get some useful ideas from my answer.

Comment: Mmmh I wonder what was wrong in what I said... Was too hard to put down a comment?

Comment: BTW, I'd like to highlight that A* uses heuristic approach. Thanks for the -2.

Comment: Your answer amounts to, "Ditch A* and its ilk and roll your own".  That can be the beginning to a reasonable answer but you provide very little info other than the suggestion.  It think the reason for down voting is you don't make it clear how difficult your solution would be to implement.  I do not doubt that a super genius given unlimited time could hand code/tune a pathing algorithm for a given RTS that would be superior to A* on a navmesh.  But "genius" and "unlimited" are very hard to come by.

Comment: Oh... Right. I thought that the guy wanted a generic answer, since he didn't ask how to make one, but how do they work in general. Anyway I'm not an expert as I said: I was just giving some info about the solutions I know about exploring large spaces in a general IA application. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Map is a grid. Grid is a graph. A* works on graph, it is a graphs searching algorithm. A* should search few nodes of graph.

As has been mentioned they can use navigation mesh. But the A* (or something similar) will be on top of that mesh anyway, because polygons of this mesh are just nodes of a graph; A* will then search for path from one polygon to another polygon.

Not sure about Warcraft or commercial games, but there is also technique called [Collaborative Diffusion](https://web.archive.org/web/20160514000233/http://sgd.cs.colorado.edu/wiki/Collaborative_Diffusion) and it is very simple; it is usually done on grid. There is also technique called [Potential Fields](https://web.archive.org/web/20190725152740/http://aigamedev.com/open/tutorials/potential-fields/), which is very similar to previous one if not the same.

You might also try:

- whether some of these games have source code available
- whether some of clones of these games have source available
- whether SDK or editors don't hint something
- ask employers of companies making these games, some of them might be willing to share

Answer (score 0):

Most games do use some sort of Search Algorithm or A* to find paths on a map. The AI is tweaked in some aspects obviously for performance reasons.

You will notice this in Starcraft 2 where Zerglings obviously don't path well at all, it would be a CPU nightmare to do that for Zerglings. They just do there best to get from A to B and don't even attempt to find the best path. They will get as close as possible then bottle neck at the chokes or ramps.

Answer (score 0):

Those older games probably did use grids and standard A* but maybe with additional optimisations such as jump search A* or simply tweaking the heuristic. There's also basic techniques that can be applied like staggering path requests across several frames or grouping path requests for groups of units.

More modern rts games like Starcraft2 may use [navmesh](https://www.jdxdev.com/blog/2021/07/06/rts-pathfinding-2-dynamic-navmesh-with-constrained-delaunay-triangles/) or [flowfields](https://www.jdxdev.com/blog/2020/05/03/procedural-ui-header-bar/).

Comment: This answer seems to repeat content already present in other answers from years ago. It might be worth editing the post to focus more on the parts that are not covered elsewhere, like the staggering and grouping techniques you mention.